# Send keyboard event to QML application

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qml, qt-signals

I would like to send a Qt::Key_Left signal to my app from a thread. 
I tried to send my event with the following code but nothing happens :  
`QKeyEvent *event = new QKeyEvent ( QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_Left, Qt::NoModifier);
QCoreApplication::sendEvent (app, pressEvent);`
Actually, these functions are called from a thread that was listening on a port. Is that possible the problem is caused by the fact that these functions are not called from the main thread ?

I just let you know that my app is in QML (don't know if it changes something). I also tried with the static function `QCoreApplication::postEvent`

Thank you in advance.
Sorry for my english level.

Comment: According to the documentation, QCoreApplication::postEvent is thread safe. However, did you try running it from the main thread?

Comment: No, I didn't and I don't see how to do it. The main thread is busy with QGuiApplication::exec, I don't know how to take control of it.

Comment: You don't 'take control of it'. You just cause it do do something. For example you could emit a signal that the main thread is connected to. The main thread will then execute the slot.

Comment: So I tried to figure it out with this : https://pastebin.com/AnpwA7km and still nothing is happening in my  QML window.

Comment: See my answer edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem came from the system and the user, it is necessary to focus the windows on the system to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

> No, I didn't and I don't see how to do it. The main thread is busy
>   with QGuiApplication::exec

The main thread is not really locked, there is a period between each event loop cycle where it listens for events from other threads.

You can use use `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()` or trigger a slot via a signal, in both cases using `Qt::QueuedConnection`, that will use that listening window to schedule the call to be performed in the next event loop cycle of the associated thread.

`QCoreApplication::postEvent()` should work, I am using that to send events from a custom on-screen controller implemented in QML and it works fine, however QML does live in the main thread, so presumably your issue is that you are sending from a different thread. So I assume if you schedule the events to be sent through the main thread it will work as expected.

EDIT:

OK, I figured out what's wrong, for some reason, posting the event to the core application instance doesn't forward it to the qml engine and subsequent qml objects. But if the receiver is set to the root qml object `engine->rootObjects().at(0)` it works... somewhat...

Events are received for items in focus via `Keys.onPressed` and similar, so if that's all you need then you are all set. Strangely enough, if I use something like a `TextEdit` this approach doesn't work to write text to the field, although emulating things like using the arrow keys to move the cursor does work. I can even press the shift modifier and select text. But not write text...

So maybe it is not as straightforward as expected. Hopefully someone will be able to shed light on the issue. For me this is all too typical with Qt, quite too often very simple and apparently logical things end up not working as expected or at all, because of some weird implementation detail.

Here is the code I used:

```
class Worker : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
  public slots:
    void forwardKeyEvent(int k) {
      sendKeyEvent(k);
    }
  signals:
    void sendKeyEvent(int k);
};

class Controller : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
  public:
    Controller(QQmlApplicationEngine * e) : engine(e) {
      w = new Worker;
      t = new QThread;
      w->moveToThread(t);
      connect(this, SIGNAL(sendKeyEvent(int)), w, SLOT(forwardKeyEvent(int)));
      connect(w, SIGNAL(sendKeyEvent(int)), this, SLOT(receiveEvent(int)));
      t->start();
    }
  public slots:
    void receiveEvent(int k) {
      QCoreApplication::postEvent(engine->rootObjects().at(0), new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyPress, (Qt::Key)k, Qt::NoModifier));
      QCoreApplication::postEvent(engine->rootObjects().at(0), new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyRelease, (Qt::Key)k, Qt::NoModifier));
    }

  private:
    Worker * w;
    QThread * t;
    QQmlApplicationEngine * engine;
  signals:
    void sendKeyEvent(int k);
};

// QML side
  Column {
    TextEdit {
      width: 400
      height: 200
      Keys.onPressed: console.log("pressed ", event.key)
      Keys.onReleased: console.log("released ", event.key)
    }
    Row {
      Repeater {
        model: [Qt.Key_Left, Qt.Key_S, Qt.Key_Right]
        delegate: Rectangle {
          width: 50
          height: 50
          color: "red"
          Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: modelData
          }
          MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: Work.sendKeyEvent(modelData) // this is actually the worker controller
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

It does some crazy back and forth in order to test inter-threading event posting, from QML to the C++ controller to an object in another thread, and back to the controller which then posts the event. It does work as intended - the data from the secondary thread is correctly posted to the event loop, but the posted events do not work as expected.

Comment: Thanks, could you give me the name of the SLOT in which I need to send my signal ?

Comment: Any slot of any object that lives in the main thread, from which you post the events. It doesn't have to be any in particular.

Comment: So i tried this : [link](https://pastebin.com/dVhuyewi) and when the lambda function is called nothing is happening on my QML window. I compared the QThread::currentThreadId() of my lambda and of the main and those are the same. Do you have an idea ?

Comment: It has to be a slot function of a QObject derived type in order to get the queued connection thing to work.

Comment: This is what I use and it works as expected https://pastebin.com/k3bGyr71

Comment: The var app is an hinstance of QGuiApplication (that inherits of QObject I think)

Comment: But you are not referring to a **member** function that is marked as a slot and thus registered in Qt's meta system.

Comment: Furthermore there are two basic connection formats, one that takes in 4 params (aside from the optional connection type) - a sender object and signal and a receiver object and slot, and another one that only takes 3 params - sender object and signal and a free function. You pass a receiver object and essentially a free function which is ill formatted and probably shouldn't even compile.

Comment: Finally, as made evident by the snipped I posted, in my particular case I had to post both a key press and a release event in order to get the expected behavior.

Comment: So i tried to apply what you said [here](https://pastebin.com/AnpwA7km), and still nothing is happening in my QML Window.

Comment: I tried to adapt [here](https://pastebin.com/QLhKeuvi) what you said in your edit it still doesn't work. I'm thinking about switching myself to sewing instead of coding

Comment: In your case the worker is actually the apiExternalLink object, and all you need is the receiveEvent slot of the controller you connect to. The rest was just a part of my test and is not needed. Qt can be as much of assistance as it can be a hindrance. It works very well if you do "regular" things with it, but is full of bugs and design limitations that are extremely obstructive if you try to do something fancier with it. I myself have to keep reinventing wheels to work around Qt's flaws.

Comment: Also - bad idea creating and populating this map each and every time. For few values just use a switch. Or make the map a class member and init in the constructor and reuse.

Comment: So I modified my code [here](https://pastebin.com/b4DSGmqu) to make it corresponding to your edit, and still is nothing happening.